# coldfusion loop variable increment value

Tags: variables, coldfusion, increment, cfloop

I'm working on outputting a graduated payment schedule that increases every 24 months.  I'm having some trouble getting the payment value to increment correctly so that payment 2 is the total of the initial payment times the increment.  Then, payment 3 is a total of payment 2 times the increment.  For example, the first couple of payments should look like this...

Payment 1:  $274.22 increase payment $13.64 
Payment 2:  $287.86 increase payment $15.03 
Payment 3:  $302.18 increase payment $15.78 
Payment 4:  $317.22 increase payment $16.57

and so on...  The increment is .04975.  The initial payment times the increment + the original payment amount becomes the payment 2.  Then, the second payment times the increment + payment 2 becomes the third payment.  The third payment times the increment + the third payment becomes payment 4, etc...

I was working with a loop, like this...

```
<cfset loopterm = 360 />
<cfset incr = .04975 />
<cfset gradinital = 274.22 />

<cfloop from="1" to="#( loopterm / 24 )#" index="i">
   <cfset newamt = newamt + ( gradinitial * incr ) />
   <cfoutput>
      #dollarformat( newamt )#
   </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Problem is the increase is always the same amount and does not graduate.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close, but you're using the same `gradinitial` value in every calculation, so your increase value is always the same.

```
<cfset loopterm = 360>
<cfset incr = .04975>
<cfset newamt = 274.22>

<cfloop from="1" to="#( loopterm / 24 )#" index="i">
  <cfoutput>
    #dollarformat(newamt)#<br />
  </cfoutput>
  <cfset newamt = newamt + ( newamt * incr ) />
</cfloop>
```

This produces a result set like this:

```
$274.22
$287.86
$302.18
$317.22
$333.00
$349.57
$366.96
$385.21
$404.38
$424.49
$445.61
$467.78
$491.05
$515.48
$541.13
```

It's not perfect, but hopefully that gets you on the right track.

Comment: Using `<cfset newamt += newamt * incr>` makes things a little simpler

Comment: Speaking of not being perfect, is it my imagination, or is this an infinite loop?

Comment: @DanBracuk it's not infinite. From 1 to 15 in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input.  I thought I had tried setting the value again before the next iteration of the loop.  Let me give that a try and I will select the appropriate answer.